# Howto order by inner element in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get firestore data ordered by **progress[0].score.**

I could not figure out how I can pass this info to orderBy method of collection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this kind of feature isn't available to the Firebase console, it is merely rendering your data in a generic format that favors alphanumeric sorting. any filters you apply in the Firebase web console does not affect how it is received within your clients app and would require additional sorting.

for example:

```js
const list = snapshot.data().progress.sort((a,b)=> a.level - b.level)
```

Comment: I can use orderBy on a collection, but I could not find a was to do it on array element. Your suggestion would work but I need to fetch all records which I don't want to do.

Comment: then you will need to restructure your data as you cannot orderby nested dynamic values